# pass data between javascript and native code (iOS - obj c, Android - java) in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Is there any way to pass data between my react-native Javascript code to native code? I want to run perform an HTTP request with a user ID when the app terminates, but from what I can see, there is no way to do that in Javascript, so the only way to do that would be within the native code. But is there any way I can get the user ID from the native code?

Comment: check [Ways to pass objects between native and JavaScript in React Native](https://medium.com/shoutem/ways-to-pass-objects-between-native-and-javascript-in-react-native-c3dcae7bf4f5)